# check unique username when updating user details jquery modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

i'm using jQuery modal for user create and update for my laravel project. when creating new user im checking the username availaibilty. but that function doesnot support with update , when user save data without changing username it gives usernam availble error . please advice how to fix

my controller,

```
public function checkUsernameAvailability()
{
$user = DB::table('users')->where('username', Input::get('username'))->count();

if ($user > 0) {
    $isAvailable = FALSE;
} else {
    $isAvailable = TRUE;
}

echo json_encode(
    array(
        'valid' => $isAvailable
    ));

}


jQuery modal
                        username: {
                            validators: {
                                notEmpty: {
                                    message: 'The Username field is required'
                                },
                                rules : {
                                    username : { alphanumeric : true }
                                },
                                remote: {
                                    url: "{{ URL::to('/checkUsername') }}",
                                    data: function (validator) {
                                        return {
                                            username: validator.getFieldElements('username').val()
                                        }
                                    },
                                    message: 'The Username is not available'
                                },
                                stringLength: {

                                    max: 100,
                                    message: 'The Username must be  less than 100 characters long'
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

Comment: disable the save button when the ajax request completes and if the result is already taken or use a global js variable and set true/false when ajax success and use the variable in the validation.

Comment: @AbdullaChozhimadathil : the thing is this function perfectly works on creating new user. But when updating user it gives error even if user update profile without changing username pls advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

**New Code To Be Added**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#username').data('actval',$('#username').val());
});
```

**Changes In Your Code Javascript**

```
username: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'The Username field is required'
                            },
                            rules : {
                                username : { alphanumeric : true }
                            },
                            remote: {
                                url: "{{ URL::to('/checkUsername') }}",
                                data: function (validator) {
                                    return {
                                        username: validator.getFieldElements('username').val(),
-----------------------                     actusername: $('#username').data('actval')
                                    }
                                },
                                message: 'The Username is not available'
                            },
                            stringLength: {

                                max: 100,
                                message: 'The Username must be  less than 100 characters long'
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

**Changes in PHP code**

```
public function checkUsernameAvailability()
{
    $user = 0;
    if(Input::get('username') != Input::get('actusername')){
       $user = DB::table('users')->where('username', Input::get('username'))->count();
   }


if ($user > 0) {
    $isAvailable = FALSE;
} else {
    $isAvailable = TRUE;
}

echo json_encode(
    array(
        'valid' => $isAvailable
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1-You can send some parameter in ajax as you know if it is update or new. And you can check it at server side for calling checkUsernameAvailability() based on the parameter value only when it is new user. In the case of update you don't need to call that method.

2- Or don't call ajax if this the case of update for checking user availability.

Comment: yes wht i did was create another fucntion checkUsernameAvailability() for update, but i want to check when user update if usernmae didnt change with db it wont give any error for username avaliable, if user change usernmae only it should match with db have any other. pls advice

Comment: can you tell me your table structure so that I can help you out

Comment: Or do one thing pass username value as 2 parameters 1 will be actual which you can keep on the username attr like "$('#username').data('actval',$('#username').val()) only first time when page loaded and you can fetch it by using $('#username').data('actval'); and paas it to your data function in javascript with actual and fetch the data based on it from db and compare username of db with the changed username from UI

Comment: my table structre is id , usernmae, full_name , password

Comment: can you kindly tell me how i can adopt ur suggestion in to my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if the username already exist in the table before submitting the form, user .on('blur') of jQuery and call for the function checkusernameAvailability(), then catch the response and after that on the basis of change the function either create user or update user. Hope this will help you.